# How using generate in fork block in system verilog

Tags: system-verilog

favorite
In my testcase, I write one program like below"

```
define NUM_TEST 10
program test();
   bit [31:0] a[NUM_TEST]; 
   bit [31:0] b[`NUM_TEST]; 
   .... 
   initial begin 
     ..... 
     fork 
        aaa (a[0], b[0]); 
        aaa (a[1], b[1]); 
        ................ 
        aaa (a[9], b[9]); 
     join 
     ..... 
  end 
  task aaa (bit [31:0] a, bit [31:0] b); 
    ..... 
  endtask 
endmodule
```

As you see, I call task aaa with NUM_TEST time (I want all tasks excuted at the same time). Is there any way to reduce my code such as:

```
  **fork
      genvar k;
      generate
         (for k=0; k<NUM_TEST; k++) 
            aaa(a[k], b[k]); 
      endgenerate 
    join**
```

(Of course, above code is wrong syntax);

FYI: I don't want to use like :

```
   fork 
      for (int i=0; i<`NUM_TEST; i++) 
        aaa(a[i], b[i]); 
   join
```

-> this is wrong for my idea because task executed in order, not the same time.

Please help me :(

Comment: Oh, it get wrong syntax when I submit this question. My old code is :

Answer (score 3):

What you want is a combination of `fork/join_none` and `wait fork`

```
module test;
`define NUM_TEST 10
program test();
   bit [31:0] a[`NUM_TEST]; 
   bit [31:0] b[`NUM_TEST]; 
   .... 

 initial begin 
     ..... 
       for (int i=0; i<`NUM_TEST; i++) 
         fork
            automatic int j = i;        
            aaa(a[j], b[j]); 
         join_none
       wait fork;
     ....
   end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to ask about **wait fork**. It will wait for all fork's submit task finished. In this case, I just want to wait all tasks aaa() finished, so If I have any other fork -join-none block, does it wait for those task too?

Comment: You can put the those `for` loop till the `wait fork;` codes in another task to make sure that the `wait fork` only wait the `aaa()` threads.

Comment: @ThinhNguyenQuoc, `wait fork` waits for all child processes of the process that executes the `wait fork` statement.  Do not confuse that with `task` or `function` calling as that does not create another process by itself. Child processes are only created by statements inside `fork` block. It just so happens that your fork statement is task call, but any procedural statement inside a fork creates a process. So @AldoT's advice is not correct.